# Solr DisMax" or "Extended DisMax" parser in Moodle

Tags: php, solr, moodle

I have setup Global search in Moodle by using Solr search engine. Now my search is working like "Full-text" search. I want to use this search like dismax query parser too.

In other words,  My Solr is currently using the "basic" query parser instead of the more advanced "DisMax" or "Extended DisMax" parser.

For example, if I search for Spiderman or spiderman or SPIDRMAN or spider-man all of the string provide the same result.

currently, If I searched for "Spider man" then no result found whereas I want to display the same result as "Spiderman" get.

thanks to advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the cases you've mentioned is something that would be different with the dismax or edismax handler. They're all related to how the content of a field is processed when indexing or when querying, and the field type is what determines that. If the field type is a regular string field, or a textfield with a keyword tokenizer, the result would only match if you have the exact same value.

However, for "spider man" to match "spiderman", you'll have to add a [ShingleFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-ShingleFilter) when querying (if you want to match "spiderman" when searching for "spider man") and indexing (if you want to match "spider man" when searching for "spiderman"), with the tokenSeparator set to "".